# R: Error in as.environment(pos) / Error during wrapup: no item called "package:[package]" on the search list

Tags: r, namespaces, package, dependencies, cran

This is similar to [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-as-environment-pos-no-item-called-package-package-on-the-search-list/75585) but with a followup question:

I'm preparing my package for submission to CRAN. In one script, it gives the titular error:

```
Error in as.environment(pos): no item called "package:shapefiles" on the search list
```

or

```
Error during wrapup: no item called "package:shapefiles" on the search list
```

If, like the similar thread linked above, I add

`attachNamespace("shapefiles")`

Then I no longer get that error, but instead I sometimes get the error or warning:

```
namespace(shapefiles) was already taken
```

I believe this happens if the function/script is run more than once. What's so weird about this to me is that

```
#' @import shapefiles
```

is in that script's markdown block,

Which means

```
import(shapefiles)
```

is in NAMESPACE, and

```
Imports:
    shapefiles (>= 0.7),
```

is in DESCRIPTION. I have numerous other package dependencies which are imported the same way (correctly, I believe), and none of them produce this error. I don't see why this is behaving differently therefore, and would like to avoid having either issue before submitting to CRAN. The code that calls this package, in my script, is

```
shapefiles::read.shapefile(savename)
```

Script is [here](https://github.com/SimonDedman/gbm.auto/blob/master/R/gbm.basemap.R), for reference.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Edit: steps to reproduce:

```
setwd("/folder")
library(devtools)
install_github("SimonDedman/gbm.auto")
library(gbm.auto)
gbm.basemap(bounds = c(-81.7, -80.3, 24.7, 25.9),
            savedir = "/folder")
```

I've just removed `shapefiles::` from the code. The correct output is produced regardless.

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? Are you compiling and installing your package when testing? Like using `devtools::load_all()` or something else?

Comment: Hi Flick, thanks for the response. I've retried the current code (with attachnamespace commented out) a number of times now and the titular error is no longer happening. No idea what I changed or why this is, but it seems fine now so I guess I'll leave it & hope it doesn't occur again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved itself after commenting out `attachNamespace("shapefiles")`. No idea why.